# what is linked orders in prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I am using prestashop 1.5.5. but i don't find any usefull information on linked orders how they created and how they can be resolved. Please my attached screenshots of prestashop. i complete one order from frontend but in admin panel i can see two invoices against one order and they both contains each other's invoice ids please help me to solve this problem

[image: order invoice part1]

[image: order invoice part 2]

Comment: i've just got the same thing dont know how though; any idea how u ended up in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

An order is splitted when you have products that one carrier can't deliver all products by himself.

If you need two or more carriers to deliver all products, Prestashop create two linked orders. You can then generate a delivery pdf (sorry don't know how it this document called exactly in english).

By the way, be carefull at the moment (PS 1.6.0.14) there is a bug on total paid amount when the order is splitted in 3 "sub-orders" or more.